# The Usual Suspects what's the joke?

Tags: dialogue, translation, the-usual-suspects

This is basically an attempt to revive this [yahoo question](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080619205537AARzu95) which has exactly one answer that is downvoted. (I'm not the OP there though)

Apparently there is a [brick joke](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrickJoke) in *The Usual Suspects*.
At around 46:20 the english part is told. I understand the following:

> So anyways, I get out of my car and the thing is wrecked. And I look in the backseat of the other car and this woman's totally naked. I'm laughing so hard I can't breathe.

According to IMDb and others later on "two Hungarians leaving a building by the docks before the climactic finish at the boat" (~1:14:50) tell the punchline. In Hungarian. But no one on the internet citing this 'trivia' seems to speak Hungarian. The aforementioned answer on yahoo even suggests that it's a hoax.

So my question is: What is said by those 2 Hungarians?
Also helpful: What do they say in Hungarian? Is there any proof that they don't actually say the punchline?

Comment: I tried watching this scene on the dvd with subtitles on just now, and of course nothing is displayed >:(

Comment: Actually,  I just watched the scenes with the director commentary turned on and they do confirm the joke IS continued with the Hungarian guys.  They don't actually say the translation, just that     "these guys are the guys... the characters in the joke"  and "they are the guys in the other car".  That at least dismisses the notion that it is a hoax, and maybe encourages others to round up their Hungarian speaking friends for translation!!

Comment: By the way, Hungarians speak **Magyar**.  Like Finnish it is a language unrelated to most European languages.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> "...és követeli tőlem, hogy mutassam meg a biztosításomat"

means something like:

> "...and she's demanding me that I showed my insurance!"

Comment: Google translate says "*and require me to show you my insurance*"

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).